# HTTPS proxy certificate is not validated

Tags: python, python-requests

I wanted to know if there is an option to validate HTTPS proxy certificate when using `requests`.

Seems like the proxy certificate is ignored even when `verify=True`

```
>>> requests.get("https://www.google.com", proxies={"https": "https://100.117.2.81:3129"}, verify=True)
>>> <Response [200]>
```

I also reported this question on the git repo:
https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/6103